# why auto-correlation still exists after accounting for AR1

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

I have a dataset including several yearly time series of different sites. I established a predictive climate–abundance association using

```
M1<-gam(abundance~Temperature+s(Temperature,Site, bs="re")+s(Site,k=11,bs="re")+s(Year,bs="tp",k=5), method="REML", family = binomial(link="logit"),weights = Trap,data=c2)
E1=resid(M1)
acf(E1) 
pacf(E1)
```

[image]

To fix the auto-correlation, I have tried both increase the k value for `s(Year)` and `s(Year,by=site)`as suggested, and also include AR1 (also tried ARMA with combinations of p=1 or 2 and q=1 or 2), but the model still have autocorrelation. For example, I fitted with AR1:

```
M2<-gamm(abundance~Temperature+s(Temperature,Site, bs="re")+s(Site,k=11,bs="re")+s(Year,bs="tp",k=5),correlation = corAR1(form = ~ Year|Site), method="REML", family = binomial(link="logit"),weights = Trap,data=c2)

E2=resid(M2$lme,type = "normalized")
acf(E2) 
pacf(E2)
```

[image]

And fitted with ARMA(1,3):
[image]

I'm confused why the autocorrelation structure doesn't account and is there anything missed in the model? Thanks.

Comment: You are better off using a time series model rather than a GAM. It's hard to model autocorrelation with a GAM effectively, since it uses smoothing.

Comment: I agree with @user2974951 but, just for curiosity, what happens when you use the Arma(p,q)? Here you have posted the results for the AR only, where it seems that the residual correlation after fitting the AR has a finite-lag decay after 3 lags, so what happens visually if you fit let’s say a ARMA(1,3) or ARMA(2,3)? Can you post it?

Comment: Thanks. I already posted the results fitted with ARMA(1,3). The model has convergence problem when fitted with ARMA(2,3).

Comment: Thanks I saw that, it shows a marginal improvement but still some autocorr remains at lag1, confirmed by the PACF. Just a question: how many data are you using? Do you think it may be a problem of insufficiently large sample?

Comment: I have thought about this. But I'm afraid its not the reason here. I could model autocorrelation for another abundance parameter (part of this annual one in the model) using AR1 for the same dataset. But thank you guys, I will consider your suggestions.

Comment: why don't you post your actual data as the acf/pacf may be affected by "other issues" other than memory thus obfuscating the model identification issue . If the data is proprietary simply double scale it and post the scaled/modified values